# How to enable websocket message compression deflate (with rsocket protocol) in spring boot (with netty server)

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, compression, netty, rsocket

I want to enable permessage-deflate compression on server side in netty environment using websocket and rsocket. My handshake right now look like this:

[image]

I am using dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-rsocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Is any property in spring boot to support this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

By default the permessage-deflate compression is disabled on the server side in netty environment.
You need to define a bean `WebSocketService` with reactor-netty and set the compression to true to activate it:

```
@Bean
public WebSocketHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter(WebSocketService webSocketService) {
    return new WebSocketHandlerAdapter(webSocketService);
}
@Bean
public WebSocketService webSocketService() {
    return new HandshakeWebSocketService(
    new ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy(WebsocketServerSpec.builder().compress(true)));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Useful answer, especially the request/response headers which I compared with my own app to see that permessage-deflate was not configured